# Apply real-time mathematical operation to state in React, elicit change in output/state/dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, state

This is the starting point of my error:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is simply take that number and perform the mathematical operation of multiplication upon it- in this case multiplying it by `0.2`- however- my program contains a heinous bug which- rather than performing that operation- simply appends `20` to the string in the text box, as you can see here:

[image]

This is the code I'm trying to use to apply the operative logic, to me it seems perfectly reasonable- though admittedly I'm not a world class expert in JavaScript, nor React. Is there something blatantly wrong with the following code snippet?

```
addLogicToEquation(newLogic) {
  let equation = this.state.equation

  if(newLogic==="10%"){
    let newEquation = equation + (equation * 0.10)
    this.setState({equation: newEquation})
  }
  if (newLogic==="15%"){
    let newEquation = equation + (equation * 0.15)
    this.setState({equation: newEquation})
  }
  if (newLogic==="20%"){
    let newEquation = equation + (equation * 0.20)
    this.setState({equation: newEquation})
  }
  else{
    // we're adding more numbers
    let newEquation = equation + newLogic
    this.setState({equation: newEquation})
  }
}
```

Perhaps that snippet is reasonable, and the flaw is elsewhere in my program- I'm really not even sure where to begin looking, the [complete codebase](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/rehackt-calc) can be found here, it's not really very voluminous- something on the order of- 10 files or so.

Comment: Try `let newEquation = Number(equation) + (Number(equation) * 0.20);` I am suspecting that equation is a string and not of type number.  If that works I can explain it better as an answer!

Comment: tried that- didn't werk

Comment: What is the value of newEquation after my codes executes? You can check it just by `console.log(newEquation);`.  If you can provide it in a jsbin that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: for some reason it works for `0.20` but none of the others :/

Comment: Check my answer, it should help!

Comment: JavaScript has a handy function `parseFloat(x)` which converts the input to a float if applicable. `console.log(x)` is also a handy tool to use to debug the app as well as `console.log(typeof x)` to give the type of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pull the value from `this.state.equation` it returns a string.  You will want to convert it to a number to be able to perform math operations on it.  In javascript to concatenate strings the `+` operator is used, so it treats your equation as a string concat.  To easily fix this, convert the value of the equation in the state to a number when you handle the initial assignment. `let equation = Number(this.state.equation)`.  Here is a your full code:

```
addLogicToEquation(newLogic) {
  let equation = Number(this.state.equation)

  if(newLogic==="10%"){
    let newEquation = equation + (equation * 0.10)
    this.setState({equation: newEquation})
  }
  if (newLogic==="15%"){
    let newEquation = equation + (equation * 0.15)
    this.setState({equation: newEquation})
  }
  if (newLogic==="20%"){
    let newEquation = equation + (equation * 0.20)
    this.setState({equation: newEquation})
  }
  else{
    // we're adding more numbers
    let newEquation = equation + newLogic
    this.setState({equation: newEquation})
  }
}
```

I'd also like to make the recommendation to refactor it to the following:

```
addLogicToEquation(newLogic) {
  let equation = Number(this.state.equation);
  let newEquation = equation;

  if (newLogic.includes("%")) {
    const percent = Number(newLogic.replace('%', '')) / 100;
    newEquation += (equation * percent);
  } else {
    newEquation += newLogic;
  }

  this.setState({ equation: newEquation });
}
```

This will allow for you to easily modify any of the percentages without having to go in an make a bunch of changes.  It will be much more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `newLogic` here contains the string `"20"`.

In JavaScript, if you add a number to a string, both parts will be converted to a string and concatenated:

```
var out = 100 + "20"; // "10020"
```

To force an addition instead, explicitly convert the string to a number, e.g. using the `+` prefix:

```
var out = 100 + +"20"; // 120
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your string to a float before the operation:

```
const string = "100";
const casted = parseFloat(string);
const output = casted + (casted * 0.15);
```

Of course you can just use 1.15 instead and avoid the addition

```
const output = parseFloat("100") * 1.15;
```